# putting model variables inside js code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, variables, razor

i have issues alternating js and razor syntax.

i am trying to pass the value of a model variable to a javascript function, let's say something like this

```
<script>
    //this is my javascript function setTitle that simply changes the title 
    of a modal window, and i want to pass to it the title from the model
     ...
     setTitle(@Model.titleName);
     ...
</script>
```

so when i do this it doesn't work, and the script seems to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a string you have to surround it with quotes.

```
setTitle('@Model.titleName');
```

If it's an integer you obviously don't need that.

In situations like these it's helpful to Right Click -> View Source, and take a look at the javascript it generated, and also report any errors the console window showed when asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encase the Razor code in quotes so the result is a JavaScript string

```
setTitle("@Model.titleName");
```